# C# distance (mile/km/etc.) string parsing library

Tags: c#, parsing, distance

Are there any C# libraries out there that provide the same kind of functionality google does when you type in a query such as "13 miles 743 yards in meters" it will return "21 600 meters" (for example).

What I want to be able to do is give a function the string part `13 miles 743 yards` and it spits back an int/double with the given distance in meters.  It needs to be able to handle all unit input types (kilometers/meters/furlongs/miles/yards/...) but the output only has to be in meters.

It isn't that hard to write my own, but it would be great to just have a tested library ready to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any answer to this, so I built my own :)  The only real 'magic' here is the Regex expression to grab the groups of values/units out of the original string.  From there it's simple fraction/number parsing and then working out how many meters each unit represents.  I have not tested this much at all, so please let me know if you find improvements or bugs (the code below should throw an exception when it can't handle a situation).

It won't handle stupid user input, but provided the format of each section is "[number] [unit]" I think it should work fine.  There is not much you can assume if the input doesn't conform (e.g., `12/32/43` or `1.43.3.2.44` as a value) anyway.  I think it will handle extra fluff in the sentence too such as `1 kilometer and 10 miles` (will strip out the `and`).  I haven't added every unit possible, if you know of a complete list of units & there meter equivalent I would love to know about it.

Here are a couple tests,

```
var a = ExtractDistance("1 1/16 Miles 3/4 yards");
var b = ExtractDistance("02234890234.853 meters");
var c = ExtractDistance("1.8 miles 3.2 furlong");
var d = ExtractDistance("1 kilometer");
var e = ExtractDistance("1/16 Miles");
```

and here is my code:

```
private static Dictionary<string, double> _DistanceLookup = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
  {"mile", 1609.344},
  {"furlong", 201.168},
  {"yard", 0.9144},
  {"inch", 0.0254},
  {"foot", 0.3048},
  {"feet", 0.3048},
  {"kilometer", 1000},
  {"kilometre", 1000},
  {"metre", 1},
  {"meter", 1},
  {"centimeter", 0.01},
  {"centimetre", 0.01},
  {"millimeter", 0.001},
  {"millimetre", 0.001},
};

private static double ConvertFraction(string fraction)
{
  double value = 0;
  if (fraction.Contains('/'))
  {
    // If the value contains /, we need to work out the fraction
    string[] splitVal = fraction.Split('/');
    if (splitVal.Length != 2)
    {
      ScrewUp(fraction, "splitVal.Length");
    }

    // Turn the fraction into decimal
    value = double.Parse(splitVal[0]) / double.Parse(splitVal[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    // Otherwise it's a simple parse
    value = double.Parse(fraction);
  }
  return value;
}

public static double ExtractDistance(string distAsString)
{
  double distanceInMeters = 0;
  /* This will have a match per unit type.
   * e.g., the string "1 1/16 Miles 3/4 Yards" would have 2 matches
   * being "1 1/16 Miles", "3/4 Yards".  Each match will then have 4
   * groups in total, with group 3 being the raw value and 4 being the
   * raw unit
   */
  var matches = Regex.Matches(distAsString, @"(([\d]+[\d\s\.,/]*)\s([A-Za-z]+[^\s\d]))");
  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
    // If groups != 4 something went wrong, we need to rethink our regex
    if (match.Groups.Count != 4)
    {
      ScrewUp(distAsString, "match.Groups.Count");
    }
    string valueRaw = match.Groups[2].Value;
    string unitRaw = match.Groups[3].Value;

    // Firstly get the value
    double value = 0;
    if (valueRaw.Contains(' '))
    {
      // If the value contains /, we need to work out the fraction
      string[] splitVal = valueRaw.Split(' ');
      if (splitVal.Length != 2)
      {
        ScrewUp(distAsString, "splitVal.Length");
      }

      // Turn the fraction into decimal
      value = ConvertFraction(splitVal[0]) + ConvertFraction(splitVal[1]);
    }
    else
    {
      value = ConvertFraction(valueRaw);
    }

    // Now work out based on the unit type
    // Clean up the raw unit string
    unitRaw = unitRaw.ToLower().Trim().TrimEnd('s');

    if (!_DistanceLookup.ContainsKey(unitRaw))
    {
      ScrewUp(distAsString, "unitRaw");
    }
    distanceInMeters += value * _DistanceLookup[unitRaw];
  }
  return distanceInMeters;
}

private static void ScrewUp(string val, string prop)
{
  throw new ArgumentException("Extract distance screwed up on string [" + val + "] (bad " + prop + ")");
}
```

Enjoy!  I hope someone out there finds this useful.  Please leave comments/suggestions.

**EDIT**: added a `,` to the regex string to handle `1,300 meters` style format

Comment: Just to note, I only just finished coding this up in the past hour.  I will be testing it more thoroughly over the coming days, but put it up here already in case others spot bugs I don't.  I will update this answer if any bugs are found.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make a request to google then parse the returned html.

**Update:** This will be really inefficient, but they have taken care of the hard work for you.  To make this work, you would have to make a English (for your example) language parser to take the input, strip out the meaningless words/symbols (like *and* and commas), find the values (13 and 743), find the units (miles, yards, and meters), find the operators (in or to).  After that, you have to make sure that it makes syntactical sense.  You also have to keep a table of conversions (not hard).

It's definitely possible, but it's a bunch of work, and I'm not sure if one exists already (other than google).  There are so many corner cases you have to worry about.  Making a library to do the work would be a fun exercise, but it is difficult to catch all cases.

The easier solution would to be give them discrete controls to take the language parsing out

Comment: I wouldn't say calling an online service every time I want to parse a distance is 'clever'.  Especially if you want to parse the distance offline, which is totally reasonable.

Comment: Ok, It's not really 'clever' but it works.  They have already taken care of the language parsing

Comment: It's still terribly in-efficient, not to mention the reliance on google/the network/latency.  It'd be like querying an online service everytime you want to know how many hours there are in a day.  Total overkill.

Comment: As per my comment @Abe, I think you are overcomplicating the solution.  I should have said, but input is only english.  Number format will always have `,` = thousands seperator (if it exists) `.` = decimal point (if it exists).  There are no operators, I only require output to meters.  Even google can't parse bad user input, it's just a fact of life :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a unit conversion library.  Doesn't have all of your desired units of measurement (furlongs!?) but looks to have most:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/Measurement_Conversion.aspx

Haven't found anything with the string parsing.  Honestly that seems like an error prone way to get input.  Consider:

- 13 miles **and** 743 yards in meters
- 13 miles 743 yards **to** meters
- 13 miles **and** 743 yards **to**
  meters

All mean the same thing and even if you give painfully specific instructions about how to write out their string they will probably do what makes sense to them...

If you want to get into what people are TRYING to say then you really might be better off going with Google.  Otherwise you might try fielding the specific inputs.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating my question.  Output only has to be meters, so the `to meters` or `in meters` part of the string does not exist.  Stripping out the `and` fluff is naturally done too.  I have no choice for the input, I just am required to parse these semi-well formed strings into distances.  If I had a choice I wouldn't be asking the question :)  And every method to solve the problem will have errors, there is only so much you can do.  If the string is in a bad format, that's just tough luck and the parse will fail.